# Custom font for table in lwuit?

Tags: user-interface, java-me, lwuit

In my application, I used custom font for table component using resource file. I created one font in resource file

```
Font.size = 10
Font.Face = Times new roman

Resources res = null;
res = Resources.open("/lang.res");      
font = res.getFont("SMALL_FONT");

Table table;
table = new Table(tableModel);
table.table.getStyle().setFont(font);
```

But I couldn't get the small font, it displays the default mobile font.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion is possible that you are setting the ´Style´ to the wrong `Component`.

I am testing it with the LWUIT Resource editor and the Deafult MIDlet (wich have a table `Form`), and changing the TableCell UIID, I can modify the font style. Try with this UIID.

Comment: The example is the next: Open the resource editor, create a new theme, and set in the preview options, the Default MIDlet. Press the table button and now you can see a table in the Preview screen. Change de unselected UIID of TableCell and see how the cell of the tables change. You can change TableHeader too... try it

Comment: You can also derive table and override createCell to customize the font of the individual cell.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your phone it may not work.  For instance, on BlackBerry it always returns the same font and I get the same behavior on Samsung B2710 J2ME phone.  I get around the issue by using bitmap fonts and loading them from resources.